# Able to log in without activating account using Restful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication

All of the restful authentication in my rails application is working but users are able to log in **without** activating their account.

When they use the URL that is emailed to them the account is activated (the activated_at column is updated).

Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the user.rb model there an authenticate method that should look like this:

```
def self.authenticate(login, password)
    return nil if login.blank? || password.blank?
    u = find :first, :conditions => 
        ['email = ? and activated_at IS NOT NULL', login]
    u && u.authenticated?(password) ? u : nil
end
```

If the account has not been activated the activated_at field will be NULL, if NULL do not allow the user to login until the account is activated.

Comment: didn't even think about checking in the model.  that was the issue.  it was commented out for testing.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly, you have to use the switch --include-activation to get it to work with activation.

If you have the time, i would suggest that you switch to Devise for authentication, though. It's much more Rails 3 oriented.

Comment: activation is setup.  it sends emails and seems to do all the activation stuff but lets users log in.  I will look into it though.  I did not do the initial development on the authentication so I am not sure this that parameter was used.